# Do we need to guard the input traces of an audio power amplifier?

Tags: pcb, amplifier, analog, audio, power-amplifier

This is a continuation of this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/690660/audio-power-amplifier-layout-clarifications).  I am using an [LM4670SD/NOPB](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4670.pdf?ts=1701063433909&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM4670%252Fpart-details%252FLM4670SD%252FNOPB) in my design. The IC has a 5 V supply.

The input of the power amplifier (+IN & -IN) comes from a smart module from [Quectel](https://www.quectel.com/product/lte-sc206e-smart-module-series).

Please see the schematic below.

Do we need to provide guarding for +IN and -IN on the PCB layout?

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Below is the reference design provided by Quectel for line out.

[image]

As per the reference design AC coupling is required.

Below is the details of entire audio interface of the Quectel SC206E module.We are using only MIC3 and line out.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to minimize DC input current leakage? Does the data sheet suggest that you need guarding? Maybe you have another reason to consider it.

Comment: Datasheet does not suggest any guarding.PCB layout team is suggesting for guarding

Comment: ask them why. In audio sometimes earthed traces are used around sensitive signals to provide screening (not "guarding", there is a difference) but usually only for very low level signals or where crosstalk between hostile signals is a consideration. In this case it seems unlikely but ask them.

Comment: May I know the difference between screening and guarding.

Comment: Guarding usually refers to DC input current leakage avoidance.

Comment: There is no data sheet available. How do you know you can even connect an amplifier like that? What are the voltage levels and impedances, and is the AC coupling even required or is it mandatory?  The modules seem to have a direct speaker output too, why not use that?

Comment: summary - guarding: you surround the sensitive signal (SS) with a conductor which is also driven with the signal. Now the SS and the surround are at the same potential, so capacitive effects pretty much disappear. screening : the surrounding conductor is grounded, which has the effect of protecting the SS against induced interference from external sources. You are interested in screening not guarding. PS you SHOULD pay attention to the things @Justme discusses. TBH It seems like you are trying to do a technical design without real understanding of fundamentals and that doesn't bode well.

Comment: I edited the question. Added complete details of the SC206E modules audio interface. Could you please check it. As per the reference design AC coupling is required.

Comment: @Justme,added the details of SC206E Audio interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we need to provide guarding for +IN and -IN on the PCB layout?

No, if you were worried about high frequency getting into the input terminals then it would be better to place a high frequency cap to shunt any high frequency currents to ground.

Guarding is mainly for DC applications to protect very low input bias signals. Guards also provide ~1pf range of cross capacitance depending on how long and how close the guard traces run together, which won't really make a difference for audio applications.